# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (1,4)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-learning, reshape

```
import random
import gym
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import os

env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')

state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
state_size

action_size = env.action_space.n
action_size

batch_size = 32

n_episodes = 1001

output_dir = 'model_output/cartpole/'

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)


class DQNAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)  # double-ended queue; acts like list, but elements can be added/removed from either end
        self.gamma = 0.95  # decay or discount rate: enables agent to take into account future actions in addition to the immediate ones, but discounted at this rate
        self.epsilon = 1.0  # exploration rate: how much to act randomly; more initially than later due to epsilon decay
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.995  # decrease number of random explorations as the agent's performance (hopefully) improves over time
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01  # minimum amount of random exploration permitted
        self.learning_rate = 0.001  # rate at which NN adjusts models parameters via SGD to reduce cost
        self.model = self._build_model()  # private method

    def _build_model(self):
        # neural net to approximate Q-value function:
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))  # 1st hidden layer; states as input
        model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))  # 2nd hidden layer
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))  # 2 actions, so 2 output neurons: 0 and 1 (L/R)
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append(
            (state, action, reward, next_state, done))  # list of previous experiences, enabling re-training later

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:  # if acting randomly, take random action
            return random.randrange(self.action_size)
        act_values = self.model.predict(state)  # if not acting randomly, predict reward value based on current state
        return np.argmax(act_values[0])  # pick the action that will give the highest reward (i.e., go left or right?)

    def replay(self, batch_size):  # method that trains NN with experiences sampled from memory
        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)  # sample a minibatch from memory
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:  # extract data for each minibatch sample
            target = reward  # if done (boolean whether game ended or not, i.e., whether final state or not), then target = reward
            if not done:  # if not done, then predict future discounted reward
                target = (reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))  # (maximum target Q based on future action a')
            target_f = self.model.predict(state)  # approximately map current state to future discounted reward
            target_f[0][action] = target
            self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)  # single epoch of training with x=state, y=target_f; fit decreases loss btwn target_f and y_hat
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay

    def load(self, name):
        self.model.load_weights(name)

    def save(self, name):
        self.model.save_weights(name)



agent = DQNAgent(state_size, action_size)

done = False
for e in range(n_episodes):  # iterate over new episodes of the game
    state = env.reset()  # reset state at start of each new episode of the game
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])

    for time in range(5000):  # time represents a frame of the game; goal is to keep pole upright as long as possible up to range, e.g., 500 or 5000 timesteps
        env.render()
        action = agent.act(state)  # action is either 0 or 1 (move cart left or right); decide on one or other here
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)  # agent interacts with env, gets feedback; 4 state data points, e.g., pole angle, cart position
        reward = reward if not done else -10  # reward +1 for each additional frame with pole upright
        next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, state_size])
        agent.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)  # remember the previous timestep's state, actions, reward, etc.
        state = next_state  # set "current state" for upcoming iteration to the current next state
        if done:  # episode ends if agent drops pole or we reach timestep 5000
            print("episode: {}/{}, score: {}, e: {:.2}".format(e, n_episodes, time, agent.epsilon))
            break  # exit loop
    if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
        agent.replay(batch_size)  # train the agent by replaying the experiences of the episode
    if e % 50 == 0:
        agent.save(output_dir + "weights_" + '{:04d}'.format(e) + ".hdf5")
```

I follow this video on OpenAI Gymand and wrote the code one-to-one.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYhFoMySoVs&t=2444s

Unfortunately I keep getting this error message:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (1,4)
```

I went through the code again and again and compared it with the code from the video and it is identical.

I also googled the error message and went through all the forums, but still couldn't fix the error.

The following is the entire error message:

```
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
D:\SSD\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\adam.py:114: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
D:\SSD\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:43: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SSD, line 84, in <module>
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in reshape
  File "D:\SSD\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 298, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "D:\SSD\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 54, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "D:\SSD\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 43, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (1,4)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I'm guessing `state` is set in the `state = env.reset()  # reset state at start of each new episode of the game` line.  The error says it has only 2 values, where as `state_size` assumes it has 4. Looks like `state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]`.  But I know nothing about this `env` or `gym`, so can't help you further.  Debugging code that is copied from a tutorial or video without much understanding of the underlying Python and numpy, or debugging methods is hard.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

As Patrick Huber says the Problem is, cause the different versions :

```
state = env.reset()
```

But you must not use an older version. A simple solution is to gather the info of it own

```
state, info = env.reset()
```

This work for this. But you have also to rewrite another function

```
next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
```

there you have to add another var that was new in the step function

```
next_state, reward, done, trunc, _ = env.step(action)
```

With this changes it should run nicely.

Comment: code originally from https://github.com/gsurma/cartpole  @oliver brings it up to date

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
state = env.reset() # reset state at start of each new episode of the game
```

In the new version of the gym library, env.reset () returns a tuple. This then gives a problem with the reshape:

```
state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
```

because reshape cannot process a tuple. If you use the gym library 0.12.5, a numpy.ndarray is returned, which the reshape function likes.

so, use `gym==0.12.5` and it works.